# Replacing a string that start with and end with in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update a particular url in wordpress post_content table. I have over 5000 differents urls to update for a single same one.

So in clear I have 5000 urls that all starts with :

```
domain.com/params.php?....
```

AND always ends with :

```
?e=
```

I want all those url to be replace with a single one without parameters in so they will all send to domain.com/page.html

So is there a way to replace all the urls without having to manually doing it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update post_content 
set url = 'domain.com/page.html'
where url like 'domain.com/params?%?e=0'
```

This phrases as : replace all `url`s that start with `'domain.com/params?'` and end with `'?e=0'` with `'domain.com/page.html'`.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not working. It's being written as it :

```
Update `wp_posts`
set post_content = 'domaine.com/newpage.php'
where post_content like 'domaine.com/ads.php?city=%e='
```

so it should take all the queries starting with domaine.com/ads.php?city= until e= but it is not and returning 0 value.

Some knows what is wrong ?